# How to modify the source/medium in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have a webpage, say xyz.com. and it has a product say cake and a dedicated page for that "xyz.com/cake.html". Whenever i navigate to the cake page from the homme page, it shows "direct" as source. Instead I want to differentiate the number of sessions that are directed from the home page(xyz.com) and the ones that directly visit the page(xyz.com/cake.html). I tried using scripts to modify the campaign source, but it is of no use! Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to use page level custom variables?

Comment: Are they allowed in universal analytics?

Comment: Yes, they are Custom Dimensions and Metrics now - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets